# Creating a function to create a function from list of variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-app

Apologies if the title is off, I can't possibly think of how to word it.

I am making a chrome web app and It is a sound board of sorts. Right now to define the audio and listen to a button click I have been doing it like this

```
//Variables for creating audio loads//
var heyboosong = new Audio();
var ricksong = new Audio();
var rapgod = new Audio();

//stopfunction has a button on the html that goes and will pause the sound playing. right now it's a list of every sound. I need to change it to just pause anything that plays//

function stopmusic() {
    heyboosong.pause();
    ricksong.pause();
    rapgod.pause();
//audio functions to listen to the buttons and make sure they are clicked, if so then wohoo sound//

function myboo() {
    heyboosong.src = "mp3/myboo.mp3";
    heyboosong.play();
}
document.getElementById('myboobutton').addEventListener('click', myboo);

    function rickplay() {
    ricksong.src = "mp3/rick.mp3";
    ricksong.play();
}
document.getElementById('rickbutton').addEventListener('click', rickplay);

function rapgodplay() {
    rapgod.src = "mp3/rapgod.mp3";
    rapgod.play();
}
```

Now this works all fine and dandy but It's a pain in the but. I have over 100 different sounds, not just these three listed. So I have to type everything out each time. Is there anyway I could condense this, with either Jquery or some other method?

Comment: Define just one click handler for the parent element and use `event.target.id` to play an audio?

Comment: So having one handler that looks for a click and finds out which element created it and uses it's name to trigger a function based on the name of it? @wOxxOm

Comment: you tagged jquery so you are using jquery

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer Yeah that was the idea. What do you mean?

Comment: test this https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/67wwmjop/

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer I really like this fiddle. My buttons are all in a scrolling DIV and they are formatted as such: <a class="mybutton" id="songname" href="#">Title of song or whatever I put in button</a> I am curious if that will work as if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will work but it will give you some ideas. If you can store the song title in the variable, I think it will work.

```
var mySong = new Audio();

function stopmusic() {
  mySong.pause();
}

function getSong(title) {
   mySong.src = "mp3/"+ title +".mp3";
   mySong.play();
}

document.getElementById(title+'button').addEventListener('click', title);
```

Comment: I like it. I just need to figure out how I would set the title @coriano35